# Without filling one field in form my cursor should not move to next field in javascript validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing validation to form field in client side using javascript. In my form, without filled a one field in form cursor should not move to next field. how to do this, and also give some tips to do a better client side validation. I have include my form

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="Myform" action="" onsubmit="return validationform();">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" onblur="validationform();" name="firstname" placeholder="Enter Name">
                        <p id="fname"></p>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname" onblur="validationform();" name="lastname" placeholder="Enter Name">
                        <p id="lname"></p>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="lastname">Email</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" onblur="validationform();" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Name">
                        <p id="vemail"></p>
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="submit" value="Submit">          
                </form>
```

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function validationform(){
            document.getElementById('fname').innerHTML = "";
            document.getElementById('lname').innerHTML = "";
            document.getElementById('vemail').innerHTML = "";

            if(document.Myform.firstname.value == ""){
                document.getElementById('fname').innerHTML="Enter your first name";
                document.Myform.firstname.focus();
                return false;
            }
            if(document.Myform.lastname.value == ""){
                document.getElementById('lname').innerHTML="Enter your last name";
                document.Myform.lastname.focus();
                return false;
            }
            if(document.Myform.email.value == ""){
                document.getElementById('vemail').innerHTML="Enter your email Id";
                document.Myform.email.focus();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jQuery blur event for input fields following is a example according to you case

```js
$(function(){
        $('#firstname').blur(function(e){
          if($(this).val().length <= 1){
            $(this).focus();
          }
        });
    });
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="Enter Name">
```

Dont forget to include jquery file.
For a batter validation

1. make a generic function
2. put a do-validation class in each input which you want to validate
3. call the validation function upon a do-validation class blur event
4. add a data-error attribute in your input field and value it with error message and get the error message from there and show it to user if validation failed

i will try to send you a code if i get time.

Comment: ok sure if your problem is solved do mark it as answer so other people will get it while searching for the same issue

Comment: on next Monday i will try to send you the function but you have to understand it by your self